# Perform additional query at end of every transaction (pg-promise)

Tags: pg-promise

As a potential way of storing metadata about transactions, I would like to execute a query at end end of every transaction.

I have looked at adding logic inside the `transact` event, but there does not seem to be a way to make another request using the current transaction. Is there a way that this could be done using pg-promise? Is this an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can only query against the transaction connection while inside a transaction callback. You cannot do it by handling `transact` event, it does not have the transaction connection available.

Comment: Thanks! One way I am thinking of handling this is by wrapping the connection (type `ExtendedProtocol`) in a Proxy object, as laid out in this gist: https://gist.github.com/lucasprograms/7867ccbb64d82acc5ce3f78d6d7f9aea

However, that only works if I have `noLocking: true`, which I am wary of doing. Do you think this approach be an okay way of solving the issue I laid out in my question?